# How to hide dash to dock in app grid?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 with Gnome 40.5. I was looking for a way to hide the dash while viewing the app grid accessed through the show applications button, but was unable to find an extension or setting to do so.

[image]

As seen in the image above, the dash is visible at the bottom in the app grid. Since my favourites are shown in the app grid, having the dash in this view is redundant which is why I would like to remove it.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Note: I only want the dash hidden while viewing the app grid. I still want it visible on my desktop and in the overview.

Comment: Perhaps the solution would be to stash the icons you don't need in a folder.

Answer (score 2):

> You can hide the dash with the following command:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.dash.hide();'
```

> You will need to add this command to your autostart programs to have
> it in effect after each login.
>
> Alternatively, the Gnome Shell extension Just Perfection by
> JustPerfection includes within the many settings an option to hide the
> Dash.
>
> Hiding the dash in the overview will also hide the Ubuntu dock on the
> desktop. To still have a dock, your only option will be to use a third
> third party dock, e.g. Plank. What you presicely want is not possible
> (at least without coding or lacking an extension for that), and you
> have to live with the Dock also appearing in the overview.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379146/how-to-hide-dash-to-dock-in-app-grid

Comment: The linked question is mine. I found no satisfactory answers there, which is why I've asked it here again with a bounty.

Comment: Oh, okay, that explains it. If I find a solution, I will update the answer.